# How to skip over nodes for insertion sort of a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, nodes, doubly-linked-list, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

Trying to implement Insertion sort function for a doubly linked list, can't get out of the bubble sort.

After every iteration of the 'swap' it is supposed to print the whole DLL, hence why I have a print in the middle of the for loop, however I can't get the code to skip over nodes that are bigger, they just swap, which is not insertion sort but bubble sort. Any help or advice?

```
void insertionSort(ofstream &fout){
    node *cu, *j, *temp;

    int length;
    length = getLength(head);
    if(head == nullptr || head->next == nullptr){
      return;
    }
    for(cu = head->next; cu != nullptr; cu = cu->next){
      temp = cu;
      j = cu->prev;
      while(j != nullptr && j->data > temp->data){
  
      cout << print(head) << endl;
      j = cu->prev;
      }
    } 

}
```

The Doubly Linked List I'm trying to sort:

```
40 34 49 13 21 1 3
```

my output:

```
[34,40,49,13,21,1,3]
[34,40,13,49,21,1,3]
[34,13,40,49,21,1,3]
[13,34,40,49,21,1,3]
[13,34,40,21,49,1,3]
[13,34,21,40,49,1,3]
[13,21,34,40,49,1,3]
[13,21,34,40,1,49,3]
[13,21,34,1,40,49,3]
[13,21,1,34,40,49,3]
[13,1,21,34,40,49,3]
[1,13,21,34,40,49,3]
[1,13,21,34,40,3,49]
[1,13,21,34,3,40,49]
[1,13,21,3,34,40,49]
[1,13,3,21,34,40,49]
[1,3,13,21,34,40,49]
```

Comment: I don't see how the code you have shared could produce that output as there is nothing in that code that alters the list.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues:

- The code you have shared does not alter the linked list: there is no assignment to a `prev` nor to a `next` member, nor to `head`.
- The `while` loop will risk to be an infinite loop, as the value of `j` doesn't change. It always is `cu->prev`.
- `getLength` is called, but the resulting `length` is never used. It is not necessary to make this call.
- The parameter `fout` is never used. Instead the function should take `head` as parameter.
- The algorithm should *extract* the `cu` node once it is decided that it should move, and once the insertion point is found, it should be *inserted* back into the list. If this node moves to the very start of the list, `head` should be updated.

Here is a correction and completion of your code:

```cpp
void insertionSort(node* &head) {
    node *cu, *j, *temp;

    if (head == nullptr) return;
    for (cu = head->next; cu != nullptr; cu = cu->next) {
        temp = cu;
        j = cu->prev;
        if (j->data > temp->data) {
            cu = j; // Prepare for next iteration
            // Remove temp from the list
            j->next = temp->next;
            if (temp->next) temp->next->prev = j;
            // Find insertion point
            while (j != nullptr && j->data > temp->data) {
                j = j->prev;
            }
            // Insert temp back into list
            temp->prev = j;
            temp->next = j ? j->next : head;
            if (j) j->next = temp;
            else   head = temp;
            if (temp->next) temp->next->prev = temp;
        }
    }
}
```